# How Do I Give Permissions for BuyCraft Through Console Commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering what the command to give a permission through console is. A *permission*, not a group, through the console?

Answer (score 2):

If you do happen to be using [Group Manager](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager/Commands) or [PEX](https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki/Commands) use the following commands:

Group Manager:

```
manuaddp <player> <permission string>
```

PEX:

```
pex user <user> add <permission> [world]
```

<> Being mandatory
[] Being optional

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the permissions plugin that you're using. If you're using [PermissionsBukkit](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/permbukkit/), you would do:

```
/perms player setperm <player> <[world:]node> [true|false]
```

(`/perms` is shorthand for `/permissions`)

Check out the [Commands](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/permbukkit/pages/commands/) page of the PermissionsBukkit docs for more info.